# How do I convert an unsigned long into single precision floating-point in x86 Assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64

`cvtsi2ss` works for integers up to 2^63 - 1 but I need 2^64-1.
There seems to be `vcvtusi2ss xmm1, xmm2, r/m64` but it always returns an Illegal instruction. If this is the function I am looking for, how do i have to properly use it?

Comment: You need to handle numbers with the MSB set by hand. PS: the compiler has no problem doing this, you don't need assembly.

Comment: see demo https://godbolt.org/z/3eawCJ

Comment: `vcvtusi2ss` is an AVX512 instruction.  It's too bad Intel didn't introduce unsigned conversions earlier, or with an extension that all CPUs can implement without needing 512-bit vectors :/